# Constructor not in Scope / Pattern matching parse error

Tags: list, haskell, tree

I have the following datatype:

```
data Tree a = Node [Tree a]
```

and I want to count how many nodes are in such a tree so I defined the following:

```
count:: Tree a -> Integer
count [] = 0
count Node label [childrenTree a] = 1 + count a
```

which gives me an error saying "Parse error in pattern: true". If I change `childrenTree a` to `Tree a` it says that the data constructor is not in scope.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tricky part in General Trees to take account, you have the function in the Tree itself, and you have the recursion over the list of tree so.
  Another thing is, you tree as it is, doesn't save any valuable information, you can change it a little bit as:

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] deriving (Show)
```

and the two functions will be like:

```
count:: Tree a -> Integer
count (Node _ trees) = 1 + countLs trees

countLs []     = 0
countLs (t:ts) = (count t) + (countLs ts)
```

and a little demo:

```
genTree1 = NodeG "1" [NodeG "2" [],
                         NodeG "3" [NodeG "4" [],
                                   NodeG "5" [NodeG "6" [],
                                             NodeG "7" [],
                                             NodeG "8" []
                                             ]
                                   ]
                         ]
```

> runing example:

```
$> count genTree1
8
```

Comment: So this somehow works without running into the type matching error that I got earlier, Im not quite sure how you managed to get around that. How would you do this for the height of a tree? My current implementation tries to mimic yours but Im failing to nail it:

```height:: Tree a -> Integer
height (Node _ (x:xs)) = 1 + maximum height' (x:xs)
height' (x:xs) = map height (x:xs)```

I was hoping that height' would map height over the whole list and the maximum would return the maximum value of this list but somewhere things seem to be going wrong.

Comment: @AdityaSubramanian that's a total different question, and you should add it as a new question. For now, if some of this two answers works for your, accept one, and move on with a new question, because if we mix all the questions in one, further readers wont understand

Answer (score 4):

This specifies that function `count` has three arguments, which is not what you want:

```
count Node label [childrenTree a] = ...
   -- ^1   ^2    ^3
```

Further,

```
count [] = ...
```

specifies that there is a single argument, which must be a list (an empty list, to be exact). You want `count` to take trees as argument, not lists.

The right way to write the code is:

```
count:: Tree a -> Integer
count (Node subtrees) = ...   -- here, we have subtrees :: [Tree a]
```

Alternatively:

```
count:: Tree a -> Integer
count (Node [])     = ...
count (Node (t:ts)) = ...
           --here t is the first tree in the list, ts is the list of remaining ones
```

---

Here's a complete working program:

```
data Tree a = Node [Tree a]

count:: Tree a -> Integer
count (Node [])     = 1
count (Node (t:ts)) = count t + count (Node ts)

-- a little test
main :: IO ()
main = print (count (Node [Node [], Node [Node[], Node[]]]))
```

The output is `5`, which is the number of `Node`s in the input.

Comment: Why do I not want three arguments?

 ```count [] = ..``` is supposed to be a base case for the recursion so it will stop when we are at the bottom of the tree. How do I implement this?

Comment: "Why do I not want three arguments?" Because `count` takes a single `Tree a` and returns an integer. That's only one argument, as your type signature shows.

Comment: I expect you just forgot, or didn't realise you needed, parentheses, and intended `count (Node label [childrenTree a])`, which is a single tree argument. (Although seemingly for a tree type which has data attached to the nodes, which yours doesn't. That in itself is unusual - the `a` in the type definition isn't actually used.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Indeed, and `[childrenTree a]` is not a valid pattern anyway.

Comment: @AdityaSubramanian See my last edit for an approach which is more similar to yours, where you can recurse.

Comment: So I indeed forgot (ok didnt realize) that I need to have parentheses but is the folloiwing implementation faulty? It seems to return the correct values. 

```count:: Tree a -> Integer
count (Node a [childrenTrees]) = 1 + count childrenTrees
```


@RobinZigmond I was thinking that a in the type definition would be an object with type Tree with identifier a but that does not seem to be the case?

Comment: @AdityaSubramanian That will fail once there is more than one children, since `[childrenTrees]` matches only with lists of length _one_.

Comment: Alright I understand!

However I tried implementing as per that realization as the following  


``` count:: Tree a -> Integer
count (Node a (t:ts)) = 1 + count t + count ts
```
but now ghci fails because it cannot match the expected type "Tree a2" with the actual type [Tree a]. I get a similar error when I try to implement a height function as the following: 

```height:: Tree a -> Integer

height (Node a [t:ts]) = 1 + max(height child, height forest)```

Comment: @AdityaSubramanian `Node` also takes one one argument; you keep try to match it with *two*. Your type declaration doesn't include a label in a `Node` value.

Comment: @chepner I seemed to have confused myself properly. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like I cannot edit previous comments in this thread so I will try re-formulate.

I tried to implement count as the following

```
count:: Tree a -> Integer
count (Node _ []) = 0
count (Node _ (t:ts)) = 1 + count t + count ts
```

but as ts is a list of (remaining) trees ghci will not compile due to not being able to match types. (ts is a list of trees and count needs a single tree). After trying to google my way out of this I have gotten quite stuck.

Comment: @AdityaSubramanian That's a nice progress. `1 + count t + count ts` sounds almost right. You are right when you say that `count ts` is wrong, since you need a single tree there, instead of a list-of-trees. Fortunately, `Node` is a constructor which can turn a list-of-trees into a single tree, so you need to exploit that, and everything should be fine (you'll need parentheses).

Comment: I have tried to add Node and Node (ts) to various places but Im not quite sure I understand what you mean. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: I did try that but I receive a similar type of error as earlier:   

Couldn't match expected type `Tree a0'
                  with actual type `[Tree [Tree a]] -> Tree [Tree a]'